# Build Bazel on LXC ARM take very long time

Tags: bazel, lxc, arm7

I am using LXC ARM7l Architecture and tried to build bazel onto it but it takes 50 hrs and still building at that moment !! I think that is very long time and it still printing some lines like those

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp43n.png)

There is something not right, isn't it ? what is it ??

thanks for advice.

Answer (score -1):

There is definitely something wrong, please file an issue on https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new

Comment: Thanks, I will do that .